# Algunos widgets de tkinter no son visibles en MacOs

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, macos

Estoy recién instalando python3 en una mac m1 pro, el problema es que en el código que estoy realizando al ejecutarlo las ventanas no muestran textos, imágenes o cuadros de texto, lo único que funciona bien son los botones. Pero mas que no mostrarlo es que se encuentran invisibles, porque respeta los tamaños de la imagen y las posiciones de las cosas, incluso al pasar el mouse por la ventana este responde a donde en teoría están los cuadros de entrada de texto, pero ni al escribir en ellos se ve lo que ingresas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que ya instale las librerías de Pillow y tkinter desde la terminal con brew, al igual que python3. Pero ya no sé que más hacer. Les dejo el código de mi programa, pero ya hice pruebas con varios códigos de prueba de tkinter y se comporta igual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido a [es.so]. Antes de nada, agrega siempre tu código como texto no como una imagen. Si lo agregas como una imagen dificultas mucho que otros usuarios que quieran ayudar puedan reproducir tu código fácilmente, ademas no indexa en búsquedas futuras y dificulta la visualización en dispositivos móviles. Simplemente copia el código, pegalo en la pregunta, luego lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl + K` o el botón `{}` del editor para que quede formateado como un bloque de código.

Comment: Por otro lado, no parece un problema del código, ¿que versión de Python, tkinter y TCL usas? Puedes ejecutar `from platform import python_version;import tkinter as tk;print(f'Python: {python_version()} | Tk: {tk.TkVersion} | Tcl: {tk.Tcl().call("info", "patchlevel")}')` en un script o interprete interactivo de Python y te debería mostrar esa info.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que el codigo esta tirando error en un punto posterior a la creacion de la ventana top level y por eso solo alcanza a mostrar solo ese widget.

Me parece que esta relacionado al formato de la ruta de la imagen que entregas para abrir la imagen. tengo entendido que en MAC OS no se utiliza el "/" si no que se utiliza otro caracter, para evitar este error te sugiero que utilizes el metodo join() de path del modulo os.

```
os.path.join( ruta, nombreimg)
```

Este metodo detecta el sistema operativo en que se esta ejecutando tu codigo y conecta las strings con las cuales generas la ruta con el correcto caracter del OS en donde se ejecuta.